# How to queue rails calls so function isn't run in parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have some rails code that calls model1.func1().  A controller action calls this, where multiple people can be hitting it, as does a scheduled rake task.  I want to make sure that model1.func1() cannot be called in parallel.  If another thread needs to call at the same time, it should wait for model1.func() to finish.  I guess I want to queue these calls.  I was going to use sidekiq for this, but with only one worker.  I read on a forum that

> Sidekiq is not appropriate for the serial job and I don't want to make
>   it appropriate.  Different tools are useful for different reasons,
>   jack of all trades master of none, etc.

What do you guys recommend instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider [beanstalkd](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) with one worker process.